# try/catch doesn't catch ItemNotFoundException

Tags: powershell

I use `try..catch` to handle exceptions.
Why the following `ItemNotFoundException` is not caught?

```
try {
    Get-Item c:\temp\no-such-file.txt
} catch {
    $err = $_.ExceptionMessage
    Write-Output "$err"
}
```

Comment: `Get-Item c:\temp\no-such-file.txt -ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: http://wragg.io/powershell-try-catch/ see #1